# How to get $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME) string (in Swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode, string, bundle, ios-extensions

In **Swift 3**, We can get `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` from `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier`.

For bundle name, we can access to `info.plist` and retrieve it as below.

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String
```

How to get `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)` string? I know that *space* will be replaced by `_`. But I want *the string* to be dependable, not hard-coded.

Comment: I found a workaround. If your class is in the same module, you can code `className.components(separatedBy: ".").first!` where `className` is a property of `NSObject`.